# Probability of a number repeating three times

Tags: probability

In the game of roulette with $37$ numbers, what is the probability of a number repeating three consecutive times?

For example,

$26, 13, 10, 10, 10$

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Do you choose the number before it appears the first time, or will any number do?

Comment: Are we always playing it five times?

Answer (score 2):

We need to make the problem precise. Assume that it is an American wheel, with $38$ slots, of which $36$ have numbers.

Assume all slots are equally likely, and assume independence. This is not necessarily a safe assumption. The problem is not so much slight imperfections in the wheel as fraud.

The probability that a particular number repeats $3$ times, in $3$ rolls (consecutive or not) *specified in advance* is $\left(\frac{1}{38}\right)^3$.

The probability that **some** number (in the range $1$ to $36$) repeats $3$ times, in $3$ rolls (consecutive or not) specified in advance is $36\left(\frac{1}{38}\right)^3$.

One can ask many related questions, which have accessible but more complicated advance. For instance, we can ask for the probability that in $5$ say consecutive rolls, there will be a number that occurs at least $3$ consecutive times.

Comment: Why $36$ and not $38\left(\frac{1}{38}\right)^3$?

Comment: I think because it was about repeating numbers, where the other two fields $0$ and $00$ do not count.

Comment: Hmm. I can't see that as the reason, it seems silly to disregard those.

Comment: If you do not wish to disregard these, multiply by $38$ instead of $36$ in the "any repeat" analysis. The reason I left these out is that they are to a roulette player special: house wins.

Comment: That clears it up. I figured you had a reason I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use a binomial distribution with probability of success being 1/37 you would get the result you are looking for.